# Update Dictionary in NgRx Entity

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-entity

I'm trying to update or rather insert new value into dictionary under ngrx Entity.

Here is simplified view of Entity:

```
interface Dictionary<T> { [key: number]: T }

export class Item {
  id: number;
  partsDescriptions: Dictionary<string[]>;
}

export interface ItemsState extends EntityState<Item> {
}
```

Here is app state:

```
export interface AppState {
  items: ItemsState
}
```

In reducer I'm trying to do following:

```
on(MyActions.partDescriptionsLoaded, (state, action) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      items: adapter.updateOne({
        id: action.id,
        changes: {
          ...state.items[action.id],
          partsDescriptions: {
            ...(state.items[action.id] && state.items[action.id].partsDescriptions),
            [action.partId]: action.partDescriptions
          }
        }
      }, state.items)
    }
  })
```

PartDescriptions dictionary is not extended, it's always replaced. Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: All you have to do to make it working is to use entities property from EntityState iterface: ...(state.items.entities[action.id] && state.items.entities[action.id].partsDescriptions)